# URL route Catch all

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wondering if there is anyway to achieve a url like http://www.mycompany.com/user in MVC
I tried using the catch all but could not get the user passed so I can do the look up.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'could not get the user passed'?  Are you talking about the "user" portion of the route or some other data you're expecting?  This will likely be a routing issue and setting up a default route, or one to handle a specific scenario, isn't too difficult.

Comment: if the url is  http://www.mycompany.com/user 
I would expect to be routed to this ActionResult
public ActionResult Index(string userName)
        {
//this userName param is always null here when it should be the //string user
           UserModel model= Data.GetUser(userName);


            return View(model);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
routes.MapRoute("User",
    "{UserName}",
    new { Controller = "User", Action = "Index", UserName = "" });
```

**UPDATED:**

add this constraint to the "User" route:

```
routes.MapRoute("User",
    "{UserName}",
    new { Controller = "User", Action = "Index", UserName = "" },
    new { UserName = @"(\w|-)+" }
);
```

or add this route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Home",
    String.Empty,
    new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Index", Id = "" }
);
```

Comment: Just tried it, now "using localhost" now requests for the default route "http://localhost/MVCApp/" are redirected to User Controller with empty string for the UserName